# Starting a session with a saved config file with Openvpn3 does not work (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: openvpn

I have a file config.conf.
I can do

```
sudo openvpn3 config-import --config config.conf
sudo openvpn3 session-start --config config.conf
```

And it works. However, if I save the config file so

```
sudo openvpn3 config-import --config config.conf --persistent
```

It saves the profile in a path that does not actually exist (I can't find it)

```
/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/{profile}
```

Next time I try to start a session with session-start as above, it gives an error because the path does not actually exist from what I understand.

```
sudo openvpn3 session-start --config config.conf 
[sudo] password for jane: 
Using pre-loaded configuration profile 'config.conf'
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/{profile}
Auth User name: Jane
Auth Password:
session-start: ** ERROR ** Failed to start session
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use option --config-path like this:

```
openvpn3 session-start --config-path /net/openvpn/v3/configuration/{profile}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and that path doesn't exist. I can't even find a /net directory on my machine. Is it because it is a VM on proxmox?